# how to grep from the second space until the end of the line of a text file

Tags: grep

Have the following file test.txt:

```
2015-01-16 15:18:37 file-folder-tokyo
2015-01-16 15:15:49 a-bucket-in_london6
2015-01-16 15:07:04 1024-logs_in_europe
```

What is the syntax for grep to turn it into the following list:

```
file-folder-tokyo
a-bucket-in_london6
1024-logs_in_europe
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried anything? getting any error?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep you could write: `grep -oP '^(\S+\s+){2}\K.*' test.txt`

I'd use sed to remove the first 2 words: `sed -r 's/^([^ ]+ ){2}//' test.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`grep` stands for `g/re/p` which are the `ed` commands to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint the matching line. What you are trying to do has absolutely nothing to do with that so `grep` would be the wrong tool to try to use. The tools you SHOULD be considering using are `cut`, `sed`, and `awk`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f3 file
file-folder-tokyo
a-bucket-in_london6
1024-logs_in_europe

$ sed 's/.* //' file
file-folder-tokyo
a-bucket-in_london6
1024-logs_in_europe

$ awk '{print $NF}' file
file-folder-tokyo
a-bucket-in_london6
1024-logs_in_europe
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using grep, I would recommend using `cat` and `cut` commands as below:

```
cat tests.txt | cut -d" " -f3
```

`cat` command will read everything in the file, and `cut`will separate the line by the space field and will output the third column.

Comment: Get rid of the UUOC, all you need is `cut -d" " -f3 test.txt`.